# Is there a way to save file to device(android or ios) memory without using phonegap File Api in web application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, html

I want to know that is it possible to safe file to any device memory like sd card without using the phoneGap File API ,If possible then how can we achieve this?

Comment: do you want to store file in sd-card?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to write native (java) code and access that code from JavaScript, that's what phone gap  does,so better use what's already there.You cannot directly access device storage from JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. Cant we give the sd card path name manually like root="/sdcard/Recorded_Videos" in javascript (without using java and phonegap) @Suhas_United